# New latex environments in bookdown not showing properly in html

Tags: latex, block, bookdown

Similar to https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/200

If i add to preamble

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
```

and in my Rmd I write

````
```{problem}

What is 2+2? 

 ```
````

or I write

````
 ```{block, type='problem'}

    What is 2+2? 

 ```
````

the pdf output shows up with the word Problem with a number and What is 2+2?, but html outuput only shows up with What is 2+2? However, if I use

````
 ```{exercise}

  What is 2+2? 

  ```
````

then both html and pdf show up correctly with Exercise with a number and What is 2+2?

By looking at the .tex file, I realized it is probably because

with ```{problem} I only get

```
 \begin{problem}
 what is 2+2?
 \end{problem}
```

but with ```{exercise} I get

```
 BeginKnitrBlock{exercise}
 What is 2=2?
 \EndKnitrBlock{exercise}
```

Is this a bug or do I have to do anything for knitr to recognize the new problem environment?

Thanks!

Here is the session info

```
> devtools::session_info('bookdown')
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.383)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2018-05-13                  

Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 cran (@1.1.2) 
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
 bookdown    0.7     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 digest      0.6.13  2017-12-14 cran (@0.6.13)
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 graphics  * 3.3.2   2016-10-31 local         
 grDevices * 3.3.2   2016-10-31 local         
 highr       0.6     2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 cran (@0.3.6) 
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 knitr       1.18    2017-12-27 cran (@1.18)  
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 cran (@0.8)   
 methods   * 3.3.2   2016-10-31 local         
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 cran (@0.5)   
 Rcpp        0.12.16 2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rmarkdown   1.9     2018-03-01 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 cran (@1.3-2) 
 stats     * 3.3.2   2016-10-31 local         
 stringi     1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 stringr     1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 tinytex     0.5     2018-04-16 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 tools       3.3.2   2016-10-31 local         
 utils     * 3.3.2   2016-10-31 local         
 xfun        0.1     2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 yaml        2.1.16  2017-12-12 cran (@2.1.16)
>
```

Comment: `devtools::session_info('bookdown')` please. And [when in doubt, try to upgrade first](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it earlier. Thanks for the wonderful packages.  Added the info to original post

Comment: Even after update it is not working

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, since `exercise` is one of the [documented](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems) theorem-like environments while `problem` is not one of them. If all you want is your "Exercises" to be called "Problem" I suggest to add:

```
language:
  label:
    exr: 'Problem '
```

to `_bookdown.yml` (c.f. https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html) and use

````
```{exercise}
  What is 2+2? 
```
````

in your `Rmd` files.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that is a way around. However, I also want to define other environments eg \newtheorem{check}[theorem]{Check}, etc. I guess I could do the 'internationalization' for all theorem environments that I won't be using. However, it would be nice if both html and pdf would 'behave' the same and once a custom block is defined, it shows up the same in all formats.

Comment: @uru `\newtheorem` is LaTeX specific and is therefore ignored for all other output formats. The list of available theorem environments is [hard coded](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/fb5a274043417be32892be630e9ad4724fa41e4c/R/html.R#L500). You can file a feature request on github to make that configurable.

Comment: Ah! That explains it. I also noticed, it does not show up in EPUB. Thank you very much for your reply! I will file a feature request on github.

Comment: @uru You are welcome. You may accept/up vote the answer if you found it helpful.